# How to import more than 2k lines of .csv file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I really need a help. Here is a situation. Every monday I receive a .csv file on my Gmail Accout. Usually it is >3k rows and contains basically numeric data.

Up to now I was downloading this .csv file and copy/paste to the Google Sheets. Now I want to automate this task.

I have searched internet and found this pretty Script for Google Sheets:

```js
function getCSV() {
  // Abrir a planhilha e limpar ela
  var sheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Agrupados_por_plano");
  first.clearContents();
  // 

 var myLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Pulse MetaBase"); // specify label in gmail
 var threads = myLabel.getThreads(0,1);
 var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
 var attachments = msgs[0][0].getAttachments();
  //var content = attachments.getContentType();
  Logger.log(attachments[0].getSize());
 // 

 var csv =  attachments[0].getBlob().getDataAsString();


 var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);

var a = data.length ;
var b = data[0].length; 


  var range = first.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length);
range.setValues(data);



}
```

The script does work pretty good and I have no errors. But it imports only first 2000 rows of data. For example, I have a file with 2780 rows and 5 columns. The script I use only imports 2000 rows and 5 columns and original file size (250 kBytes) is reduced to 192 kBytes.

How would I solve it? Is it a limitation of getAttachment() method?

Comment: In order to understand correctly your situation, can you provide the detail information about ``does not import more than 2k lines of .csv file``? For example, those are the error messages, the size of CSV file and the values of CSV when it is not imported. I think that they will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. Actually script does import data, but only amout limited to 2000 rows.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. In my environment, when I tried to import a CSV data with 3000 rows, 5 columns and 400 kb in the file size, all CSV data can be imported. For example, when the CSV data is imported to new Spreadsheet, does the same issue occur? If it's so, how about confirming the format of CSV data you want to import? I'm sorry I cannot propose the concrete method because I cannot replicate your situation. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I'm sorry.

Comment: What is the line separator used by your CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue. It is all about paying attention to the code you are working on. My script was getting the same message over and over and that particular message contains .csv attach with exactly 2000 rows of data. Só what did I do? Just add few lines of code in order to get the last message in the thread every time my script is triggered.

```js
function getThreadsGmail()
{
  // pegar o último email do thread e retornar arquivo anexo
  var myLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Meta_Base_Reports"); // especificar lable em Gmail
 var threads = myLabel.getThreads();
 
  
   var msgs = threads[0].getMessages();
  var lastMsg = msgs[msgs.length - 1]; // get the last message in the thread
  var attachments = lastMsg.getAttachments();
  return attachments;
}
```

Thank you guys! =)